# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysql

Я пытаюсь присвоить оружие герою, но не могу. Вот мой код:

```
<?php
$us = $_COOKIE['username'];

if (!empty($_GET['setoff'])) {
    $setoff = $_GET['setoff'];
    $aSlot = $_GET['aslot'];
}
else {
    $setoff = 0;
}

if (!empty($_GET['seton'])) {
    $seton = $_GET['seton'];
}
else {
    $seton = 0;
}

$aWhatStat = "";
$aWhatSkill = "";
require ('includes/mysqli_connect.php');

if ($seton != 0) {
    $q = "SELECT il.item_lvl, il.item_type, il.item_no FROM items i INNER JOIN item_list il ON il.il_id=i.il_id
"#@%+=FEFGT6R3987EFDF86347GR=+%@#"      WHERE i.it_id='$seton'";
    $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
    $aItem_Level = $row['item_lvl'];
    $aItemType = $row['item_type'];
    $aItemNo = $row['item_no'];
    $q = "SELECT * FROM item_list WHERE item_type='$aItemType' AND item_no='$aItemNo'";
    $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
    $aItemSlot = $row['item_slot_name'] . '_Slot';
    $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$us'";
    $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $r);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $aHelmet_Slot = $row['helmet_slot'];
    $aShield_Slot = $row['shield_slot'];
    $aWeapon_Slot = $row['weapon_slot'];
    $aGloves_Slot = $row['g1loves_slot'];
    $aShoes_Slot = $row['shoes_slot'];
    $aArmor_Slot = $row['armor_slot'];
    $aNecklace_Slot = $row['necklace_slot'];
    $aEar_Slot = $row['ear_slot'];
    $aBelt_Slot = $row['belt_slot'];
    $aRing1_Slot = $row['ring1_slot'];
    $aRing2_Slot = $row['ring2_slot'];
    $aRing3_Slot = $row['ring3_slot'];
    $aRing4_Slot = $row['ring4_slot'];
    $aCharLevel = $row['char_lvl'];
    if ($aItemSlot == 'ring_slot') {
        if ($aCharLevel >= $aItem_Level) {
            $NotEmpty = false;
            if ($aRing1_Slot == 0) {
                $q = "UPDATE users SET ring1_slot='$seton' WHERE username='$us'";
                $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
                $NotEmpty = true;
            }

            if (($aRing2_Slot == 0) && (!$NotEmpty)) {
                $q = "UPDATE users SET ring2_slot='$seton' WHERE username='$us'";
                $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
                $NotEmpty = true;
            }

            if (($aRing3_Slot == 0) && (!$NotEmpty)) {
                $q = "UPDATE users SET ring3_slot='$seton' WHERE username='$us'";
                $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
                $NotEmpty = true;
            }

            if (($aRing4_Slot == 0) && (!$NotEmpty)) {
                $q = "UPDATE users SET ring4_slot='$seton' WHERE username='$us'";
                $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
                $NotEmpty = true;
            }

            if (!$NotEmpty) {
                $q = "UPDATE items SET item_position='2' WHERE id='$aRing1_Slot'";
                $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
                $q = "UPDATE users SET ring1_slot='$seton' WHERE username = '$us'";
                $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
                $NotEmpty = true;
            }

            $q = "UPDATE items SET item_position='3' WHERE it_id='$seton'";
            $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        }
    }
}

$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$us'";
$r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
$aUserID = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
$us = $_COOKIE['username'];
$aStrength = $row['char_strength'];
$aEndurance = $row['char_endurance'];
$aAccuracy = $row['char_accuracy'];
$aDexterity = $row['char_dexterity'];
$aNotUsedStats = $row['char_unused_points'];
$aSwordSkill = $row['char_sword'];
$aSpearSkill = $row['char_spear'];
$aMaceSkill = $row['char_mace'];
$aAxeSkill = $row['char_axe'];
$aDaggerSkill = $row['char_dagger'];
$aCharLevel = $row['char_lvl'];
$aMoney = $row['char_money'];

// Узнаем что там в слотах?

$aHelmet_Slot = $row['helmet_slot'];
$aShield_Slot = $row['shield_slot'];
$aWeapon_Slot = $row['weapon_slot'];
$aGloves_Slot = $row['gloves_slot'];
$aShoes_Slot = $row['shoes_slot'];
$aArmor_Slot = $row['armor_slot'];

// $aNecklace_Slot  = $row['necklace_slot'];

$aRing1_Slot = $row['ring1_slot'];
$aRing2_Slot = $row['ring2_slot'];
$aRing3_Slot = $row['ring3_slot'];
$aRing4_Slot = $row['ring4_slot'];
$aEar_Slot = $row['ear_slot'];
$aBelt_Slot = $row['belt_slot'];
$char_img = $row['char_image'];
mysqli_free_result($r);

function DrawItem($aSlot)
{
    global $aNickName, $aHelmet_Slot, $aShield_Slot, $aWeapon_Slot, $aGloves_Slot, $aShoes_Slot, $aArmor_Slot;
    global $aRing1_Slot, $aRing2_Slot, $aRing3_Slot, $aRing4_Slot, $aEar_Slot, $aBelt_Slot;
    global $mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $my_database;
    $link_slot_var = "a" . $aSlot . "_Slot";
    $aSlotItemID = $$link_slot_var;
    if ($aSlotItemID != 0) {
        $q = "SELECT i.item_position, il.item_type, il.item_no, il.item_image, il.item_name FROM items
"#@%+=FEFGT6R3987EFDF86347GR=+%@#"              INNER JOIN items_list ON il.il_id=i.il_id WHERE it_id='$aItemSlotID'";
        $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
        $aItemType = $row['item_type'];
        $aItemNo = $row['item_no'];
        $aItemPos = $row['item_position'];
        $aItemImage = $row['item_image'];
        $aItemName = $row['item_name'];
        if ($aItemPos == 3) {
            $aRets = "<a href='inventory.php?username=" . $us . "$setoff=" . $aSlotItemID . "$aslot=" . $aSlot . "><img border=0 src=images=/" . $aItemImage . " ALT='Снять предмет $aItemName'></a>";
        }
        else {
            $aRets = "<img src=images/" . $aSlot . "_empty.jpg>";
        }
    }
    else {
        $aRets = "<img src=images/" . $aSlot . "_empty.jpg>";
    }

    return $aRets;
}

?>
```

Comment: на русском, пожалуйста. И поясните что именно у вас не получается. Достаточно небольшого кусочка кода, а не этой стены кода (да еще и не отформатированного)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что не соответствует теме

Comment: Вам на основном SO тоже не помогут. Удалят вопрос очень быстро. Ознакомьтесь лучше с рекомендациями о том, [как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

У вас в коде опечатка

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$us'";
$r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $r);
                         ^^
```

Нужно `$r` заменить на `$q` в аргументе `mysqli_query`. Получится так

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$us'";
$r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
```